# JDBC driver class not supported with sql server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc

in my java code JDBC driver class is not supported with ms sql server 2008 while it works perfectly with ms sql server 2005

i have put jdbc driver class  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

MY CODE IS

```
import java.sql.*;

  public class MysqlConnect{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
  String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://SQLSERVERIP:1433;";
  String dbName = "DatabaseName=DBNAME";
  String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
  String userName = "sa"; 
  String password = "password";
  try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
  System.out.println("Connected to the database");
  conn.close();
  System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

while i am trying to connect it gives an error

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database "hj_cnb_ci
" requested by the login. The login failed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError
(SQLServerException.java:197)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:246
)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:83)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerC
onnection.java:2529)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConne
ction.java:1905)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$000(SQLServer
Connection.java:41)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecu
te(SQLServerConnection.java:1893)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4615)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLSe
rverConnection.java:1400)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLSer
verConnection.java:1045)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConne
ction.java:817)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerCon
nection.java:700)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.
java:842)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at MysqlConnect.main(MysqlConnect.java:14)
```

plz help me to sort out this issue..

Comment: Why are you mixing MySQL with MS SQL?

Comment: Can you show the code making the connection, including the connection details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your jdbc driver version. "Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0" is suitable for your ms sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2008,please change your driver class to -- com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver .The connection should work.

Comment: Also, use the correct jdbc jar, else you'll get the same connection error

Comment: driver class should be com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver

Answer (score 0):

Check if exists "hj_cnb_ci " or DBName created it on your DB Server

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  When answering questions, it is best to spell out things as much as possible so other readers can get the most out of your knowledge.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database name. There is no need to call `newInstance()` when you load the class; it will call its static block and call the `registerDriver()` method of the Driver manager class, and will pass its reference as a parameter.

This method carries an object of the `Driver` class. When you call the driver manager's `getConnection()` method, interally it will call drivers class method connection with the help of that object.